# CmisConnectionException : Parsing exception Error

Tags: alfresco, cmis, cmis-workbench

I am trying to remotely connect to Alfresco server using cmis workbench but i am getting below error.

> Exception: CmisConnectionException
>   Parsing exception! 
>   Cause: WstxEOFException
>   Unexpected EOF in prolog at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
>
> ---
>
> The provided URL does not return an AtomPub response.
>   Check your URL, the binding, and your proxy settings.
>
> Some servers return a HTML login page if the credentials are incorrect.
>   Check your credentials.
>
> ---
>
> Current proxy settings:
>
> - no proxy settings -

Regards.

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to? (My hunch is that it isn't the right one...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you are using the correct service URL for the given Alfresco version and CMIS binding. The list of URLs can be found [here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#CMIS_Service_URL).